# Chrome extensions: how to grab a part of html on the page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a page in active tab.
I need to find in this page a table:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="details">
```

grab it until next `</table>`-tag,
and use it (to paste it in a new tab, popup, or just in "alert").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't include jQuery for such an easy task.

```
var table = document.getElememtsByTagName("table")[0]; //if it is the first or only table, you could change 0 to any other number if the table always is at the same position
```

or you could give your table an id:

```
var table = document.getElementById("my-table");
```

to get the html just call

```
var foo = table.innerHtml;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to select the table and return the HTML. For example `$('table').html()` will return a string of the `<table>` markup.

Comment: How can I get exactly the table I want (there are many tables on the page)?
Could you provide example of code?

Comment: Replace `table` in my example with an `#id` specific to the table.

Comment: As you can see, there is no ID in this table and I cannot give the table an ID (if I could do it, why would I need the Chrome Extension?).

Comment: Unfortunately getElementsByClassName is not working for me in this case

Comment: You can throw `slice()` in there to select the tabel you want. `$('table').slice(3, 4).html()` will use the 4th table.